# Is it possible to prevent stripping of query params from shared URLs?

Tags: linkedin-api

We utilize the LinkedIn "Customized URL" to allow sharing of articles to LinkedIn users' feeds. (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)  The encoded URL that is passed into the "url" parameter contains our own tracking parameters.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thedailybeast.com%2Farticles%2F2015%2F03%2F26%2Famerica-loses-no-matter-who-wins-the-next-great-middle-east-war.html%3Fvia%3Ddesktop%26social%3DLinkedin
```

Unfortunately, the URL's to our articles shared in this way have been stripped of the query parameters.

The presumed reason is that LinkedIn ingests our og:url metadata and uses that canonical URL for the link that is shared.  We'd prefer to override this, but the docs seem to indicate that that is only possible if you use the REST API.  We'd prefer to avoid that since we are only trying to share articles to LinkedIn.  Can someone tell me if there is any other way to incorporate our tracking query params using the "shareArticle" URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you utilize the API for sharing, rather than via URL as you are doing, you can specifically provide values that LinkedIn will use, which avoids the crawler picking up the page's meta-data and "overriding" the URL you are giving it.

More information on making the API call here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: OK, that's what we figured but thought I'd check.  Thanks!