# How can I get my linkedIn sharing url to work

Tags: c#, url, linkedin-api

I am sharing my page "www.mysite.com/detail/?v=2442411"  to linkedIn but I just get a "Oops" on linkedIn.

In code I have it like this:

```
string LinkedIn = $"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={mysiteurlvariable}?v={myidvariable}&title=ThisTitle"
```

It spits out this link:
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=www.mysite.com/detail/?v=2442411&title=ThisTitle

When following the link as I say I just get a oops from LinkedIn.
Although when replacing the url with any other url also without a parameter its fine.

It seems like it does not like the ?v={myidvatiable} part

Anyone know of this issue or why this is an issue

Comment: what values do you have in mysiteurlvariable and myidvatible? (note it says vatible not variable perhaps)

Comment: Why do you have title=ThisTitle? Did you mean title={ThisTitle}?

Comment: Your URI could be malformed: the `?` is used twice. Try replacing `?v=` with `&v=`

Comment: @BugFinder mysiteurlvariable = www.mysite.com/detail/ and myidvatiable =2442411

Comment: @JakeSteffen, its just a random text used for the example. You can make it what you want like: SharingNotWorking or ISuckAtThis. lol

Comment: Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305683/is-it-possible-to-prevent-stripping-of-query-params-from-shared-urls

Comment: Also, do not forget to [HTML encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095351/encoding-parameters-for-a-url) your query string parameter values.

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Looks like you need use LinkedIn api

Comment: I agree with @n0idea it looks like html encoding issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to do [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with parameters you are feeding to another URL.  And also, since you have posted your question, the *LinkedIn Share URL parameters* have changed.  Source: [**Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin).

So, this is what you should want...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={mysiteurlvariable}%3Fv%3D%7Bmyidvariable%7D%26title%3DThisTitle%22
```

*Hope this helps!*